# How can I print out an HTML table that access 2 tables in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-managers

To get started with Django, I'm using it to build a small site for my softball team where we can list the stats of each player. For the model I've defined 2 tables - Player and Statline where the player in Statline is the foreign key.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    bats = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=HANDED_CHOICES)
    throws = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=HANDED_CHOICES)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=POSITION_CHOICES)
    pitches = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PITCHES_CHOICES)
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class StatLine(models.Model):
    season_name = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=SEASON_CHOICES)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    at_bats = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
    singles = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
    doubles = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
    triples = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
    homeruns = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
    runs = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
    rbis = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
    rboe = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=NUMBER_CHOICES, default=0)
```

What I'm looking to do is do a query where I sum up all of the stats for each player and group it by player. That way I have a running tally of all of our stats for each season. In SQL when I built the site in PHP, it was:

```
FROM Stats
INNER JOIN Players ON Players.player_id = Stats.player_id 
WHERE season_name = 'Spring 2012'
GROUP BY Players.player_name
```

I'm confused on how to use Django to perform the same query. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[Django's documentation about aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation) should be sufficient.

I don't know why you're grouping by `player_name` because you don't state which fields you want to have selected and if there should be an aggregation somewhere. Is it possible to have several `StatLine` objects for a single `Player`?

In case you want all homeruns of a particular season to be summed up for each player, you can use this snippet:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Player.objects.filter(
      statline__season_name="Spring 2012"
   ).annotate(
      sum_homeruns=Sum(statline__homeruns),
      sum_abats=Sum(statline__abats),
      sum_singles=Sum(statline__singl‌​es),
      […]
)
```

As [stated in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses), the order of `filter()` and `annotate()` is of importance.

Comment: OK that helps a ton. I'll give it a shot. The purpose is to have the stats as they would normally appear on the back of a baseball card: Player Name, Hits, Singles, Doubles, etc. - for a given season.

Comment: OK I'm still stuck. I've read through all the documentation but I'm still having an issue creating the query I need. As per the first question - yes all statlines can be thought of stats for an individual game. so for the table I want to produce, it needs to add up all of the statlines for a given player. So the query should be filtered by player and then have the sum of each of the other statline columns. Can I chain the annontatations e.g. .annotate(sum_abats=Sum(statline__abats).annontate(sum_singles=Sum(statline__singles)...?

Comment: Yes, you can add multiple annotations. See my modified example above.